Can the agile approach be applied to the Inmon Enterprise Data Warehouse approach? If yes, how?
Can the agile approach be applied to the Inmon Enterprise Data Warehouse approach? If yes, how?
I haven't found any sources that apply the agile approach to the Inmon approach. Instead, all I have found is Kimball or Data Vault. So, can agile be applied to the Inmon approach or not?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Yes, you can apply Agile approaches to Inmon Enterprise Data Warehouse. IMHO, while Inmon approach focuses on top-down design for data warehouses, Agile can be introduced by adapting the incremental development to deliver data marts and include regular feedback loops.
It would called it a hybrid approach since you are maintaining the structured governance of Inmon while you benefit from Agile flexibility to guarantee faster delivery cycles. I wrote an article you can check it here : Kimball vs. Inmon: Unraveling the Synergy of Data Warehouse Approaches
